# High pitched whistling coming from AC lines

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

Does anyone know what would cause a high pitched whistling noise to come from my AC lines when the AC isn't running? It seems like maybe there's some refrigerant or air trapped in the refrigerant slipping through a valve somewhere. I'll upload a video that has audio. I swear for a few weeks I thought I had some kind of animal hiding in my house or something.

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/1PW6CBIe1Ps?feature=share3

Answer (score 1):

When the system is running there is a great difference between the High side pressure and Low side pressure.

The whistle when the system is off is the result of equalization of pressure from high and low sides of the system. This may be exacerbated by a line touching the metal case or some other part of the unit.

Such noise from freon movement is not noticeable when the unit is running because of other noise from the fans and the compressor.

Try touching the smaller of the lines lightly to see if you feel a vibration. Look to see if it is touching another part.  If you find that, add a little insulation between the line and what it touches.
The source may be inside the air-handler.  then you need to decide if it is worth paying a tech to look inside.